# Android Studio - Theme Switch

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a simple app in Android Studio with kotlin for a school assignment and Im having an issue.. I have MainActivity along with others and also SettingsActivity... Inside settings activity I added a switch for theme which saves in SharedPreferences.. the issue is, I cant get it to initialize the theme on startup, it always does it only when opening settings..

I tried putting the initialization logic inside MainActivity, but the theme still isnt initialized correctly and when I go to settings activity, the themes are switching rapidly almost giving me a seizure.. I also tried adding it into MyApplication (which inherits from Application class) but then the button has no effect..

Here is my SettingsActivity code:

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivitySettingsBinding
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        loadSettings()

        binding.themeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
            saveSettings()
        }

        binding.backButtonSettings.setOnClickListener{
            finish()
        }
    }

    fun loadSettings() {
        val isDarkThemeEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("enable_dark_theme", false)
        binding.themeSwitch.isChecked = isDarkThemeEnabled

        if (isDarkThemeEnabled) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        }
    }
    fun saveSettings() {
        with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
            putBoolean("enable_dark_theme", binding.themeSwitch?.isChecked ?: false)
            apply()
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
import com.example.myfirstapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    private val startInputActivityLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val data = result.data
                val productName = data?.getStringExtra("productName")
                val productPrice = data?.getDoubleExtra("productPrice", 0.0)

                if (!productName.isNullOrBlank() && productPrice != null) {
                    val myApplication = application as MyApplication
                    myApplication.addProductToWarehouse(productName, productPrice)
                    showToast(getString(R.string.toast_product_added, productName, productPrice))
                } else {
                    println("The info you entered is not correct")
                }
            }
        }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initializeTheme()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        val exitButton=binding.exitButton
        val inputButton=binding.inputButton
        val aboutButton=binding.aboutButton
        val settingsButton=binding.settings

        inputButton.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, InputActivity::class.java)
            startInputActivityLauncher.launch(intent)
        }

        aboutButton.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this,AboutActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        exitButton.setOnClickListener{
            finish()
        }

        settingsButton.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }

    private fun initializeTheme() {
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val isDarkThemeEnabled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("enable_dark_theme", false)

        if (isDarkThemeEnabled) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        }
    }
    private fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

Comment: `the issue is, I cant get it to initialize the theme on startup, it always does it only when opening settings` well, are you running the code to change the theme in the start activity ? i think you'd need to post that to show what you tried and what's happening there. it's not going to change the theme automatically just because you saved a boolean into shared prefs

Comment: Fair point, I added MainActivity class.. If I go to settings now, the themes keep changing rapidly.. When I added this same code into MyApplication class, the theme switch doesnt do anything at all

Comment: when you put this in your application class, did you set the application class in your AndroidManifest as well ?

Comment: Yeahh, I have been using the MyApplication class for another thing already, so its added in the manifest.. Although ive used it in main.kt and terminal to test some stuff out, not with emulator

Comment: it has been several years some i've done something like this, to be honest, so i can't really comment too much on this. Using multiple activities is also not a standard anymore, but that's somewhat irrelevant. If i had to guess, i'd say try putting your `AppCompatDelegate.setDefault....` code into the application class, and then trigger it from there, similarly, put your `loadSettings` only in there as well. then try run the app, see if that works

Comment: Thanks.. Does the MyApplicatoin class always run first? Also, if I put loadSettings out of SettingsActivity, wont the immediate theme change from the switch not work?

Comment: `wont the immediate theme change from the switch not work?` i'm saying move EVERY reference to the theme change from your activities into only your application class and then use it from there, one function to set to light, another to dark. on switch change, call them from your application class, see if that works

Comment: This worked, thank you <33